# Inline SVG in Lithium View

Tags: php, lithium

Total newbie to Lithium.

I'm trying to inline an SVG file in a Lithium View.

In previous PHP Frameworks I would just do the following:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('images/styleguide/left-arrow.svg'); ?>
```

In Lithium this will throw a pretty epic error with regards to where it's looking for the file:

> Warning: file_get_contents(images/styleguide/left-arrow.svg): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   //app/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_styleguide_index.html_17440333_1480885998_1509.php

Because of this location I'm wondering what the "lithium way" of doing this would be (if at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this (please add answers if there is a better solution).

Use the Media class to get the root or your static files:

```
use lithium\net\http\Media;

$webrootPath = Media::webroot(true);
```

Using this you can get the file contents:

```
$watchRound = file_get_contents($webrootPath.'/images/styleguide/watch-round.svg');
```

Then inline it:

```
<button class="toolbar__btn js-styleguide-viewport-watch-round">
  <?php echo $watchRound; ?>
</button>
```